# searching for a big dataset in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am a student looking for a dataset that has at least 5000 rows. We have to perform inferential statistics in R programming. Can anyone please suggest a database?

Answer (score 2):

The `nycflights13` package has records of all flights that departed from New York City in 2013.

```r
library(nycflights13)
nrow(flights) ## 336776
```